# How to update the value of textbox based from the value of dropbox? - MySQL PHP

Tags: php, textbox

I have a dropbox and a textbox. The dropbox is populated by the value from MySQL database. What I want to do is to make the value of the textbox change dynamically based from what I select from the dropbox.

Right now, my current code is partly working. The dropbox is populated by the value from the database. But the textbox doesn't change value, it's only showing the value of the first row.

These values are in the same table.

```
id  |  person  | age | by_user  | up_date
-----------------------------------------------
AI  |  john    | 10  | "byUser" | "date updated"
AI  |  jane    | 12  | "byUser" | "date updated"
AI  |  tess    | 15  | "byUser" | "date updated"
```

This is the code in the page where I have the submit button:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include 'headers/header_on.php'; //LOGIN
    include "dbh.php"; //MySQL CONN

    $person = $_POST['person'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name";
?>

    <p id="opener">
        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['Fname'])) {
                echo "Welcome back, " . $_SESSION['Fname'];
            } else {
                header("Location: ../register.php?error");
                exit();
            }
        ?>
    </p>

<form class='data_form' action='data/update.inc.php' method='post'>

        <?php
        //DROPDOWN BOX
            echo "<select name=person id=person>";
                //PULLS DATA FROM DATABASE
                foreach (mysqli_query($conn, $sql) as $row){
                    echo "<option value=$row[person]>$row[person]</option>";
                    }
            echo "</select>";
        ?>
        <?php
        //TEXTBOX
            echo "<input type=text name=age value=$row[age]>";
        ?>

    <button type='submit'>UPDATE</button>
</form>
```

This is the code for the other php file: (update.inc.php)

```
 include '../dbh.php'; //CONN TO MySQL  

    $by_user = $_SESSION['Fname'];
    //GET CURRENT DATE YYY-MM-DD
    $up_date = date('Y-m-d');

    {
    //INSERT VALUES TO MySQL DATABASE --> DOESN'T WORK
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET age=$age, by_user=$by_user, up_date=$up_date";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    header("Location: ../index.php");
    }   
?>
```

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is to update the age of a person (in the textbox) based from the person selected in the dropbox when I click the UPDATE button. But I can't get pass to the textbox issue where the value won't update based from the value of the dropbox.

Hope anyone can help me with this. Thanks!

Just a heads up, I'm not familiar with AJAX and JQuery. I'm still learning how to program.

Comment: If you want to change the page dynamically without submitting the form, you have to do it in Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: It takes basic JavaScript to do this. PHP is run on the sever side, so you cannot change anything until server receives submitted data. JavaScript deals with the changes in the client side. With your PHP at this level, you should be able to learn how to do that with JavaScript very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and for clarifying the limitations of PHP. I will look into JavaScript. I've also read that this can be done using JQuery and / or AJAX. But I'm not sure which approach should I go with at this level.

Comment: @crispywisp AJAX is the concept/technique to asynchronously load data from a request to the back-end from the front-end. JQuery is a library of functionality that makes javascript easier to write in a faster dev time. Using jQuery to make your AJAX request will certainly make life easier for you. I recommend looking at using Ajax. Simple is best like this tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp